Update to latest dart version in aws ec2 linux instance
I am using Serverpod and terraform scripts to upload to aws server.
In my pubspec.yaml file somehow I have to have dart SDK version 3.5.0(latest one).
But after deploying to aws ec2 linux, I am getting 502 Bad gateway. It says:
The current Dart SDK version is 3.1.0(this is on my ec2 linux machine).
Because _server requires SDK version 3.5.0, version solving failed.
I tried this:
Install Dart
echo "Installing dart"

wget -q https://storage.googleapis.com/dart-archive/channels/stable/release/3.5.0/sdk/dartsdk-linux-x64-release.zip

unzip -q dartsdk-linux-x64-release.zip


sudo mv dart-sdk/ /usr/lib/dart/


sudo chmod -R 755 /usr/lib/dart/

echo 'export PATH="$PATH:/usr/lib/dart/bin"' >> /etc/profile.d/script.sh

It failed saying

cannot move dart-sdk to /usr/lib/dart/ as file already exist.

If I try to rm the dart-sdk inside usr/lib/dart/ it says

can't delete the directory

.
And after all it still shows the dart version of my ec2 linux as 3.1.0 which I want to have 3.5.0.

It says "can't delete the directory" because you need add -r and optionally -f flags to rm command.
from docs:
       -r, -R, --recursive
              remove directories and their contents recursively

       -f, --force
              ignore nonexistent files and arguments, never prompt

So your command should look pretty much like this:
sudo rm -rf /usr/lib/dart/dart-sdk

After that rm command, you should repeat another steps, starting from sudo mv dart-sdk/ /usr/lib/dart/
Also, I personally think that this way of managing Dart versions in not very convenient. Here is recommended way to install/manage Dart SDK versions with package manager: https://dart.dev/get-dart#install
UPDATED
While investigate situation in comments me and OP found couple of other problems which were not addressed in this answer, so I update it accordingly:

OP had dart SDK installed already, but in another location (/usr/lib/dart/bin). That's why he always got 3.1.0 version even if deleting directory in /usr/lib/dart/dart-sdk.

To mitigate 1, we decided to set PATH in a way that desired SDK will be earlier in path and dart will take it.

To update PATH, this command worked:  echo 'export PATH="/usr/lib/dart/dart-sdk/bin:$PATH"' | sudo tee -a /etc/profile.d/script.sh. Here we set path to desired dart sdk as first entry. And, it's important, sudo doesn't work output redirection (>>) straight away, so we used sudo tee with pipe.



Thnx on focusing on this.
I did manage to change the name and add dart-sdk inside  /usr/lib/dart/ and run the last export command still my linux machine shows dart version 3.1.0 only.
Can you guide me on how to install on linux via terminal using your suggested link https://dart.dev/get-dart#install.
As I don't know how to add get-apt package only via terminal(as suggested on your link).

First of all, can you show output of echo $PATH from your terminal? I guess that maybe last command from your list is a little confusing. Maybe it's better to move dart to, for example, /usr/local/bin or something

As of link with instructions for apt-get, you should be able to run it straight away. But, maybe if you run ec2 on Amazon Linux, then things start to get complicate and it's not possible with apt-get :(

I have little to no knowledge about linux machines, this tasks also I am able to do somehow because of my computer knowledge.
For your $PATH output is:
/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/usr/lib/dart/bin:/home/ec2-user/.local/bin:/home/ec2-user/bin:/usr/lib/dart/bin:/home/ec2-user/.local/bin:/home/ec2-user/bin:/usr/lib/dart/bin:/home/ec2-user/.local/bin:/home/ec2-user/bin:/usr/lib/dart/bin:/home/ec2-user/.local/bin:/home/ec2-user/bin.

Please help me updating dart sdk on my ec2 linux machine. As for now to run my servers,
I have downgraded my dart sdk to 3.1.0(same as linux) and also downgraded Serverpod version from 2.0.2 to 2.0.0(which supports dart sdk 3.1.0).
But you know you can't be following such scenario always in production.

Try this: 1. make sure /usr/lib/dart/dart-sdk exist and /usr/lib/dart/dart-sdk/bin/dart --version shows correct version. 2. If not - repeat steps with rm -rf and mv. 3. Run echo 'export PATH="/usr/lib/dart/dart-sdk/bin:$PATH"' >> /etc/profile.d/script.sh and then re-login to your machine 4. Check dart version again. Should be your desired version

for your step 1:
if I only run dart --version it shows up 3.1.0.
But if I follow your command that is /usr/lib/dart/dart-sdk/bin/dart --version it shows what I want that is dart sdk version 3.5.0.
Then I skip your step 2 and go for step 3 it says -bash: /etc/profile.d/script.sh: Permission denied with sudo also it says same. what to do now.

My bad, sudo not works with simply >>. Try this echo 'export PATH="/usr/lib/dart/dart-sdk/bin:$PATH"' | sudo tee -a /etc/profile.d/script.sh  and then also re-login.

Thank you so much for your time, I guess this is the step where it was stucking. what you suggest is perfect rather than this: echo 'export PATH="$PATH:/usr/lib/dart/bin"' >> /etc/profile.d/script.sh.
My linux machine now shows the desire dart version what I wanted. Thanks.

Glad it helped! I also updated answer according to this discussion. Upvotes and accepting answer is welcome and appreciated, as usual :)
